# Minimum of the falling factorial function

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I have the following polynomial (aka the falling factorial function)
$p(x):=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n)$ for $x\geq0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
How can we show that its global minimum is attained for $x\in[n-1,n]$?

Comment: This is not true, at least, for $n$ odd, as global minimums don't exist.
With that question sorted out, note as well that for $n$ even, the polynomial is symmetric over $n/2$ so you can ask for a global minimum in $x \in [0, 1]$. From this on it just seems to me like a case based computation.

Comment: The polynomial is defined for $x\geq0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that part, but in any case I think you have to get your hands dirty here. Estimate value for $x = n - 1/2$ and for any other interval you have $ - p(x) < (n-1)! 2 $
Isn't this enough?

EDIT: probably you need the stronger inequality $ - p(x) < (n-2)! 3 $ using the fact that in the second interval the polynomial is positive.

I obtain the latter inequality from pushing $x$ to the nearest integers increasing the value in each factor, and concluding with $(n-k)! (k+1)! < (n - 1 )! 2 $

Comment: Induction gives us the estimate $-p(x)\leq\frac{n!}{4}$.

Comment: If it does you any good, p(n - 1/2) is asymptotically $n! / \sqrt{2 \pi }$ which is bigger than your estimate, so this should be enough in the asymptotic case. Do you really need the general case?

Answer (score 0):

Define $p_{n}(x):=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n)$ for $x\in[0,n]$.

[image: Graphic of $p_{5}$ on $[0,5]$.]

**Figure 1**. Graphic of $p_{5}$ on $[0,5]$.

**Theorem 1**.
$\min_{x\in[0,n]}p_{n}(x)=\min_{x\in[n-1,n]}p_{n}(x)$.

Before we proceed, let us give some properties of $p_{n}$.

**P1**. $p_{n}(m)=0$ for $m=0,1,\cdots,n$.

**P2**. $(-1)^{n-m}p_{n}(x)>0$ for $x\in(m,m+1)$ and $m=0,1,\cdots,n-1$.

**P3**. $p_{n}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}p_{n}(n-x)$ for $x\in[0,n]$.

Define $q_{n}(x):=(-1)^{n-\lfloor{}x\rfloor}p_{n}(x)$ for $x\in[0,n]$.
By *P2* and *P3*, $q_{n}$ is nonnegative on $[0,n]$ and is symmetric with respect to $\frac{n}{2}$.

[image: Graphic of $q_{5}$ on $[0,5]$.]

**Figure 2**. Graphic of $q_{5}$ on $[0,5]$.

Define $h_{n}(x):=q_{n}(x)-q_{n}(x+1)$ for $x\in[0,n-1]$.

[image: Graphics of $p_{5}(x)$ and $p_{5}(x+1)$ for $x\in[0,2]$.]

**Figure 3**. Graphics of $p_{5}(x)$ and $p_{5}(x+1)$ for $x\in[0,2]$.

**Lemma 1**.
$h_{n}$ is nonnegative on $[0,\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor]$.

**Proof**.
Clearly,
\begin{align}
h_{n}(x)=&(-1)^{n-\lfloor{}x\rfloor}p_{n}(x)-(-1)^{n-\lfloor(x+1)\rfloor}p_{n}(x+1)\notag\\
=&(-1)^{(n-1)-\lfloor{}x\rfloor}p_{n-1}(x)[-(x-n)-(x+1)]\notag\\
=&[(n+1)-2x]q_{n-1}(x)\geq0\notag
\end{align}
for $x\in[0,\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor]$. $\blacksquare$

**Corollary 1**.
$\max_{x\in[0,1]}q_{n}(x)\geq\max_{x\in[1,2]}q_{n}(x)\geq\cdots\geq\max_{x\in[\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor]}q_{n}(x)$.

**Proof**.
Obviously,
\begin{equation}
q_{n}(x)=h_{n}(x)+q_{n}(x+1)\geq{}q_{n}(x+1)=h_{n}(x+1)+q_{n}(x+2)\geq{}q_{n}(x+2)\geq\cdots\geq{}q_{n}(x+\lfloor\tfrac{n-1}{2}\rfloor)\notag
\end{equation}
for $x\in[0,1]$. $\blacksquare$

**Proof of Theorem 1**.
By symmetry of $q_{n}$ and *Corollary 1*, we have $\max_{x\in[0,n]}q_{n}(x)=\max_{x\in[0,\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor]}q_{n}(x)=\max_{x\in[0,1]}q_{n}(x)$.
In view of *P2* and *P3*, this completes the proof. $\blacksquare$